# Super-puff exoplanets

Tags: exoplanet

Super-puffs are gas giant sized planets with masses only a few earth masses.

What causes planets to form with such low density and why are they so rare?

Comment: Typically they are very hot so their density is low and the reason why we don't find them is because most of them have to be relatively young to be that big.

Comment: @fasterthanlight The youth argument doesn't work for inflated Hot Jupiters. And it is not at all clear whether low-mass inflated planets and inflated HJ's shouldn't have the same inflation mechanism.